# Why won't this function count more than 10 digits?

Tags: c++, digits

I wrote this function to count and return the number of digits, or the length, of the number passed to the function. It works great until you tell it to count the digits in a number with more than 10 digits. In those cases it simply returns 1.

```
int digits(int z)
{
  int counter = 1;
  for ( double y = 9; z > y; y = (y*10) + 9)
  {
    counter++;
  }
return counter;
}
```

Comment: Can i know with what number it failed ??
and make sure you have not crossed allowed range of int in C++.

Comment: You can't actually tell this function to do anything with such a large number, because you can't pass it such a large number.

Comment: i think i see. if i declare the function and its argument as a double will that work?

Comment: @user3035328 Depends on the rest of the code. If you just cast the integer from the caller to a double it still won't, otherwise yes (rounding errors aside)

Comment: @user3035328 It will increase the range, but if you are interested in integer numbers then you might want to use `long long` or `std::int64_t` (this will most likely be faster and you won't have to worry about rounding errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integer is most likely 32 bits on your target machine.  If signed, an integer holds a value between (roughly) -2 billion and +2 billion.  Either extreme is 10 digits long.

You could change your code to work with 64-bit integers for a bit more mileage.  Otherwise you'll need to use a custom representation (ie, write your own large integer class) to allow for arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: how would one write such a class? @Steven Hansen

Comment: That's probably the subject for another post.  It usually involves an array to store individual digits in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Range of 4 byte int is from  `–2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

If you specify any positive number less than 2,147,483,647 then it will count it else it will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the range.
as for int it is **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647**
Any number less than lower limit i.e -2,147,483,648 or anything greater than Higher limit i.e 2,147,483,647 will produce 1 as result. That you have specified in the question.
[click here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44774/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues in your code:

1. Not considering negative values
2. Using floating point

To address 1.: 
You need an absolute value: int u = std::abs(z).

Attention: The absolute value of the most negative integer is not defined.

To address 2.: 
Increment the counter and decrement u if 10 <= u. After that you can use your loop with an int y and u.

In addition: Most likely the test you are performing is passing a negative number, due to an overflow in a multiplication by 10.